# Oauth2.0 how to distinguish between user A and user B ?

Tags: oauth

My app get the oauth2.0 token to access the protected resource, but how can I distinguish between users, example if there is userA and userB. UserA can access the url `/accout/info.jso?uid=2` to get his data,but my question is if userA get the token, but he access the userB's data by the url `/accout/info.jso?uid=userBId`
How oauth2.0 system avoid this kind of problem?

Answer (score 0):

In OAuth 2.0, the resource owner and the client who is requesting access are two different entities.  In your question, it sounds like they are one and the same.  OAuth exists to provide limited access to a third party, the client application.

But leaving that aside...  if you are using bearer tokens, they do not provide any identification.  The nature of a bearer token is that whoever presents it is granted the access associated with the token.  Other token types, SAML 2.0 for example, carry more semantic information about the identity of the client.

In your case, you want to verify that the user identified in the URI is the user who sent the request.  A bearer token alone will not do this.  If using bearer tokens, your resource server will need to ask the authorization server if the presented token was issued to the user whose data the client is requesting.  The authorization server will have to remember the access tokens it issued and who it issued them to.  It should also remember the scope they were issued for and when they expire so the resource server can check that the token is still active and the requested resource is in scope for the presented token.